# When using KNeighborsClassifier, what is the motivation of using weights="distance"?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-nn

When using `KNeighborsClassifier`, what is the motivation of using `weights="distance"`?

According to the scikit-learn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html):

> ‘distance’ : weight points by the inverse of their distance. In this case, closer neighbors of a query point will have a greater influence than neighbors which are further away.

What is the motivation for using this?

Comment: Read here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/weighted-k-nn/

Answer (score 5):

`weights = 'distance'` is in contrast to the default which is `weights = 'uniform'`. When weights are uniform, a simple majority vote of the nearest neighbors is used to assign cluster membership.

When weights are distance weighted, the voting is proportional to the distance value. Nearby points will have a greater influence than more distance points (even if the counts of different groups are the similar).

Distance weighting is very useful for sparse data.